# Compare files on server?

Tags: file-comparison

So my site got hacked, I thought that I managed to fix all the files and set it back up. However, the hacker managed to leave some kind of backdoor, and my site was hacked again. My site is built with wordpress, so I want to compare the clean wordpress files and my wordpress files. I know this is easily done in linux, but I'm on windows, so is this possible?

**And I don't have access to the server command line or config files, as I'm hosted**

Comment: you should back your website up now when it's working, and do regular backups on the files and database, and datestamp the backups, so when your site is hacked all you need do is replace the files on the server

Comment: My host takes backups every day, but it costs 10€ to replace my files, and as I can deal without paying anything this time, I fix it on my own.

Comment: why not try a free webhosting alternative where you can host site with your own registered domain? like 000webhost.com for instance.
ofcourse I don't have a target on my back YET so I haven't had any break-ins beyond two random defacements.
[I use wordpress also, but I like hacking into my own things with tools on backtrack every few months to check it]

Comment: You can keep your web hosting. I have my own registered domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) on Windows to compare XML files. It may work for what you ask.

(I'm assuming that you have FTP access or similar to retrieve the files)

Comment: Does it work for html,php,css,js and etc?

Comment: And yeah, I have FTP access, but I'd rather do this on the server?

Comment: Yes, any file UTF-8 or ASCII encoded file. If it can be opened by a text editor, KDiff will do the job.

Comment: Do I have to download the files first to my computer, and then compare them, or can I just do it on the server?

Comment: I though that since you don't have shell access to the server, you could download the wordpress related files and compare them in your local computer.

Comment: So it's not possible because I don't have shell access? So I'll just have to it on my computer.

Comment: As far as I know, I think so. Maybe using some script written in PHP o some other scripting language supported by your host.